# How can I use Grant-SmbShareAccess to specify more than one access right

Tags: powershell

This is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
Grant-SmbShareAccess –Name $ShareName –AccountName $_ –AccessRight ("Read,Change") -Force;

Grant-SmbShareAccess –Name $ShareName –AccountName $_ –AccessRight "Read,Change" -Force;

Grant-SmbShareAccess –Name $ShareName –AccountName $_ –AccessRight Read,Change -Force;
```

If I run the command like:

```
Grant-SmbShareAccess –Name $ShareName –AccountName $_ –AccessRight Change -Force;

Grant-SmbShareAccess –Name $ShareName –AccountName $_ –AccessRight Read -Force;
```

It only keeps the latest permission in this case `Read`, the `Change` is lost

Take a look:

[image]

Comment: What did you expect, and what actually happened?

Comment: Take a look to my updated question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grant `Read` and `Modify` both, just grant once `Full`.

```
Grant-SmbShareAccess –Name $ShareName –AccountName $_ –AccessRight Full -Force;
```

Comment: I guess that I might do that, but... it has to be a way just to specify read and change isn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, I think they are mutually exclusive. Although one problem is, the right is called `Modify` not Change.

Comment: The documentation says that it's `Modify` but I tried that on a 2012 box and it didn't work, it turns out that the correct value is `Change` at least that worked for me. I'm using `Full` as your suggestion, but I'd like to find a way to add both though

Answer (score 0):

Change includes read...just use change. (documentation is wrong, it is change not modify)

But in actuality, I don't like to rely on share level permissions. I usually just create the share with everyone:full and rely on folder level permissions.

Answer (score 0):

if set to `change` then `read` will automatically get checked